# Cannot infer arguments (unable to resolve constructor)

Tags: android-studio, android-listview, android-adapter

I am trying to make a program with a tablayout, each tab representing a fragment. In the second fragment (AddFragment), im want to make a list that displays the strings I entered in the EditText. But its giving me the error above. More detailed:

```
error: cannot infer type arguments for ArrayAdapter<>
itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(AddFragment.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
```

Code for the AddFragment class:

```
public class AddFragment extends Fragment {
EditText etPlan;
EditText etExercise;
ImageButton imageButton;
ArrayList<String> items;
ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter;
ListView listView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    findViews();
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}

private void findViews() {
    listView = getView().findViewById(R.id.listView);
    etPlan = getView().findViewById(R.id.etPlan);
    etExercise = getView().findViewById(R.id.etExercise);
    imageButton = getView().findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            items = new ArrayList<>();
            itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(AddFragment.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
            listView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
            setUpListViewListener();
        }


        private void setUpListViewListener() {
            listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Context context = getContext();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Item Removed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    items.remove(position);
                    itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The declaration that you have works if working directly in the activity JAVA file. While working in the fragment, you need to establish clearly the type of argument and provide the correct context.

The following should work (assuming that you are passing strings):

```
itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
```